# Loop through multiple dicts in list, while assigning values to incremental variables - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.9

```
x = [
   {'id': 'e5015', 'price': '2001.00000000', 'size': '0.30000000', 'time_in_force': 'GTC'}, 
   {'id': 'bdd3d', 'price': '2000.00000000', 'size': '0.10000000', 'time_in_force': 'GTC'}, 
   {'id': '32c60', 'price': '2000.00000000', 'size': '0.01770613', 'time_in_force': 'GTC'}
   {**insert varying number of additional dicts here**}
]
```

**How do we loop through this list of dicts, and assign them to incremental variables depending on how many dicts there are? (eg. z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, etc)**

```
z1 = x[0]["price1"]
z2 = x[0]["price2"]
z3 = x[0]["price3"]
z4 = x[0]["price4"]
...etc...
z9 = x[0]["price9"] # If it exists
```

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this? What advantage could multiple variables possibly have over a list in this case?

Comment: `x[0]["price1"]` will fail with a KeyError. You're neither looping through the list of dicts (it's always `x[0]`), nor getting a dict item out (since price1, price2, price3 etc don't exist as keys in the dicts).

Comment: They could possibly stay in the list, and perform the required math functions, but we would still need to be able to grab different 'price' and 'size' VALUES from dicts in the list that have identical KEYS (eg. 'price' is the same in each dict, but value of 'price' is not.)

Comment: Can you explain what you are planning to do?

Comment: regarding z1, z2... z9 - check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables It's a bad idea, use data structure

Comment: doesnt seem to apply to multiple dicts ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension and list indices instead to get your price variables

```
prices = [d['price'] for d in x]
z1 = prices[0]
z2 = prices[1]
# ...etc
```

Comment: list index out of range - (when trying to assign z5 IF z5 does not exist in list)

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to manually assign variables for each price possible

Comment: True. We can keep the DICTs, but how would we check how many items exist in DICTs?

Comment: by using `len(x)`

Comment: so after we find out len(prices) = 6, how do we set up a function that can use prices[1] through prices[6], no more no less? ( If len(prices) = 6, run through 6 times )

Comment: prices[0] through prices[5] since python indexing starts at 0

Answer (score 1):

> How do we loop through this list of dicts, and assign them to
> incremental variables...

The answer is: You don't. It looks like you're trying to iterate over the dictionaries, and only retain price information. So, why not make a list of prices?

```
prices = [d["price"] for d in x]
```